# Who invented time travel in Terminator Genisys?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-genisys

There are three time machines (or parts thereof) in Terminator Genisys. The one in 2029, the one in 1984 and the one in 2017. Pops and John Connor are able to build the 1984 & 2017 machines because they've had access to the one in the future. But who created the 2029 machine? Are we expected to believe that Skynet, who still has robots driving trucks in 2029, somehow had the creativity to invent time travel? Even if it was capable of such a thing, how would it have known it would need it?

Comment: Considering that Skynet committed mass genocide in order to protect itself, one should assume that Skynet will similarly go to any lengths to make sure its continued existence is possible. The beginning of the film explained that the time machine was built as a back-up plan should everything in the "future" went ass-end-up.

Comment: I get that it's a backup plan, but it's a crazy backup plan: the kind we usually associate with human creativity. If Skynet had somehow known that time travel existed, that would make sense to me, but that it somehow conceived of and built it on its own when it had no way of knowing it would actually work is beyond my suspension of disbelief.

Comment: I find your lack of faith disturbing.

Comment: Don't try and understand any Terminator time travel plots as there are any number of possible answers to any question.

Comment: The lower tier robots drive trucks, same as lower tier humans do generic work. Why wouldn't Skynet emulate humans after it's been monitoring their every move for years?

Comment: The truck thing is IMO an indication of how uncreative Skynet is. Why build robots to drive trucks when you could build trucks with self-driving AI, for instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I belive the 2017 machine that we see being invented with the help of John Connor is the time machine that matures for travel in 2029. In Genisys this machine is built at an accelerated rate hence can possibly get completed much ahead in time. But the machine is also damaged in the end so according to the now new timeline they have not mentioned the date of judgement day or the first time travel back.

John from 2029 is sent back with the required knowledge to 2017 to create skynet and the time machine. In part two skynet was shown to be invented because of the T800 arm left behind from part 1. In Genisys they show that the events from part 1 is over written. The first T800 is shown to be quickly destroyed. Because of this skynet will not be created. To avoid that, skynet sends John back to invent skynet. According to the terminator series skynet and john both are born as a result of the predestination paradox. Skynet and John are responsible for their own creation. Skynet sends the T800 which becomes the start point for scientists to start work on skynet. John sends Kyle back and is the one who results in Sarah conceiving John. All of skynet's tech and the resistance leader are part of a closed predestination paradox loop.

Comment: If the 2017 machine later becomes the 2029 machine, that's a loop. Who created it in the first place?

Comment: According to terminator genisys, it's the corrupted John Connor. The earlier movies don't mention who.

Comment: What's your evidence that John Connor invented time travel? I don't think the movie supports that at all. Yes he builds the 2017 machine, but only after he's been infected by Skynet and gains its knowledge of the 2029 machine.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, John from 2029 is sent back with the required knowledge to 2017 to create skynet and the time machine. In part two skynet was shown to be invented because of the T800 arm left behind from part 1. In Genisys they show that the events from part 1 is over written. The first T800 is shown to be quickly destroyed. Because of this skynet will not be created. To avoid that, skynet sends John back to invent skynet. According to the terminator series skynet and john both are born as a result of the predestination paradox. Skynet and John are responsible for their own creation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying that time travel technology has always existed in a closed loop. I don't like it, but it sort of works. Write that as an answer instead of a comment and I'll accept it.